# Use HomePod as a microphone for a audio recording?

Tags: audio, homepod

I know that you can send a call to a HomePod to use the microphone on the HomePod to talk to the person you're calling to, and use its speaker to listen to the person calling. Since it is possible to call others with the microphone on the HomePod (through the iPhone of course), is there a way to do audio recording with the HomePod's microphone (with some app like Voice Memo)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. There exist no official way of recording audio from the HomePod into for example Voice Memo or other "generic" apps.

You could use a call recording service or voice mail system to record audio from the HomePod by dialing into that system. It would be impractical and the quality wouldn't be great, so it is probably not a realistic option for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by sending a voice note via iMessage.

Say:

Hey Siri, send a voice note to [Contact Name]

Once you record your voice note and confirm, you can retrieve the recording from iMessage on a device connected to your iCloud account. By default voice notes are deleted automatically from the senders side a few minutes after they're sent, so make sure to export the voice note or press the Keep button in iMessage if you want it to stick around.

Comment: The question is about how to make calls with the Homepod.

Comment: @nohillside I believe you've misread. From the question, "is there a way to do audio recording with the HomePod's microphone (with some app like Voice Memo)?"

Comment: Ah right, indeed I did.